# Wordpress session confusion after redeploying app or deep change hhvm -> php 7

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am using

`$_SESSION` in my wordpress application without any problems.

But: when doing deep changes, e.g. redeploying the wordpress application, or when say, changing from HHVM to php 7, I all of the sudden get problems.

That is: code that always worked, doesn't work any more.

A simple store on one page, and then retrieve of a session variable on the next page, will result in retrieving null / empty.

e.g. i do

on page 1 :

```
$_SESSION['myid'] = 'foobar';
```

on page 2:

```
if(!$_SESSION['myid'] ){
throw new \Exception('illegal state');
}
```

This problem gets fixed by clearing the cache, cookies. Or: using incognito window. Or I think: relogging.

So now those problems do get solved... but we cannot force the users to do this.

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Currently we use the session handling of a parent theme that is in their `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');
function myStartSession() {

    if(!session_id()) { //if there's no session, start it
       @session_start();
    }
}


 function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the WordPress issue but when switching from HHVM to PHP did you make sure to match the `php.ini` file as closely as possible to [HHVM's](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/configuration/INI-settings)? It's quite possible that that way in which HHVM handles sessions is completely incompatible with the way PHP does it so if you have no reason to switch away from HHVM then just leave it.

Comment: Why cant you just unset the session for one time for each user? Would solve your problem

Comment: @user2831723 I don't think unsetting the session would solve it, the problem is that it seems the session is not the same between two calls.